# Bad audio quality while playing embedded HD video in phone

Tags: python-2.7, audio, mobile, encoding

I have a very strange experience of bad audio quality of an HD embedded video.

I upload my video(formats like wmv,mp4 etc..) to my CMS application which will be stored in amazon s3 and it will be encoded using "http://api.encoding.com/". After encoding i play it from the user front-end of the CMS .

The strange problem i am facing is that,some of the videos are not having good audio quality when i play it from my mobile device(iphone,samsung galaxy,windows phone). The quality is bad only when i play it through the phone speakers. Audio quality is fine when i play it through the headset.

Any Ideas on this Friends???
Please advice me on this!!!!

Thank You....

Comment: On this phone that is giving you the bad quality through it's speakers-- does normal music sound okay? YouTube videos? Trying to eliminate bad speakers on this one phone. It happens (and might be covered under warranty).

Comment: Yes, Normal music sounds perfect. im sure its nothing to do with bad speakers of phone. i have tried with multiple devices. Thanks for the reply Mike.